# Umbraco 7.6.2: Cannot bind source type <my model> to model type Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to create a custom login form with Umbraco 7.6.2 I created a partial view for the form, a model and a surface controller based on Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController.

After all that I get the error:

**Cannot bind source type 'name of my model' to model type Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent**.

Controller:

```
public class UserSurfaceController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
{
    //
    // GET: /User/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Models.UserModel user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (user.IsValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, user.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class UserModel 
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember on this computer")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if user with given password exists in the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_username">User name</param>
    /// <param name="_password">User password</param>
    /// <returns>True if user exist and password is correct</returns>
    public bool IsValid(string _username, string _password)
    {
        if (_username == "username" && _password == "password")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

View:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<IPublishedContent>  
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
@Html.Partial("User", new namespace.UserModel());
```

Partial view:

```
@model namespace.UserModel

<div role="content">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            @using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<namespace.Controllers.UserSurfaceController>("Login", "UserSurface"))
            {
                <div>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Login</legend>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.UserName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => u.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            }
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

What may I be doing wrong here? Considering this is Umbraco 7.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

In your View, you are expecting `IPublishedContent`.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<IPublishedContent>
```

You didn't provide code of that model. Double check if this model is inheriting `RenderModel`. Your `UserModel` for partial is fine.

Comment: I don't have a model for the view, it is relying on Umbraco only for that. That's probably what I am missing here... I will give it a try later today and update the post.

Comment: By not providing a model to your view, Umbraco will use its current request context to determine the current page requested and will implicitly provide that model to the View. In your case, the line "return View(user);" could be problematic, because you are providing your view with an incompatible model (UserModel) instead of expected IPublishedContent (becase your view declares it inherits it).